# authClient on mobile devices

Tags: cordova, firebase

I have a question about Firebase's auth client. I have Firebase's login system set up to work perfectly in Chrome, but when I start using emulators for mobile devices, it starts causing problems. I know that I need to set up the "Application Domains" section of the auth client so that it will know what domains to allow, but what am I supposed to put in for a mobile app?

All of my data storage is coming straight from Firebase itself so I don't know what domain I would need to add.

Comment: Engineer at Firebase here. We have a few outstanding requests to add better support for mobile browsers, PhoneGap, as well as add support for authentication flows using redirects (rather than pop-ups), which would solve your problem. I'll note your request and follow-up here as soon as we've made progress. Appreciate your patience!

Comment: Great, thank you. Aside from this, firebase works really great.

Comment: Can you also comment on which authentication providers you'd like to use (email / password, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, Persona, etc.), as well as the specific mobile environment you're targeting (iOS, Android, native app, web app, PhoneGap, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: Well, my current app is using the email / password setup and I'm trying to deploy it to Blackberry and Android using the PhoneGap build service. Eventually I'd like to be able to deploy it to iOS as well.

Comment: I saw that you guys have addressed this issue for the Facebook and Persona log-in systems. Do you plan to address email/password as well or would I be better off swapping my log in system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Engineer at Firebase] I wanted to provide a brief update on this. Firebase recently released a number of updates adding full support for Adobe PhoneGap / Apache Cordova, including fully supporting Firebase Simple Login for Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, and email / password authentication methods.

Check out the blog post at https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-16-firebase-adds-phonegap-cordova-support.html for more info!