# how to setup firebase javascript simple login with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, angularfire, ionic-framework

I have problem when using angular firebase javascript simple login with cordova.

Below is testing under `cordova emulate android`

1. user click on google login button
2. redirect to google login page
3. after submitted login form. the page stuck with loading.... please wait
4. and this error messsage in console `not allowed to load local resouces`

I got no problem when using desktop browser or mobile browser. It is just mobile app.

Anyone know what error is that?

Tools i use

- angularjs
- angularfire
- firebase
- iconic framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [authClient on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545253/authclient-on-mobile-devices); that post includes a link to blog post detailing cordova

Comment: hi kato, i don't understand. I read the blog. it seems like nothing to change with code or any setup. I also clone the demo from the blog and emulate it. Nothing work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is? Copy-paste the error message, the "not allowed to load local resources" error should also show the URL it's trying to load

Comment: @Ossama here is the error
`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/login`

Comment: @Ossama i record a screen capture. pls check it
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBN9k0prgTA

Comment: @kato i record a screen capture. pls check it
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBN9k0prgTA

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific configuration issues (and a couple of bugs that needed to be worked out) but this should work well now. Firebase has a blog post explaining how to get this  working "[Using Firebase Simple Login with Ionic and PhoneGap](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html)".

Comment: I doubled checked it.  `<access origin="*" />` I think this is allow all the external domain and inappbrowser is added. since i'm using ionic framework so `cordova.js` is included automatically. actually querying the data has no problem. just the login.   any idea?

Comment: Hrm. A bit at a loss here, we're investigating the issue internally (at Firebase) and I'll update this answer when we've got something.

Comment: @vzhen - updated my answer apologies it's taken a couple weeks.